# Install apk by link

Tags: python, django, web, installation, apk

I try to make sure that when you open a link to start the installation without downloading the apk .
The Internet has found a certain amount of information as a result of a code:

```
path = os.path.join(build.project.path, build.upload_file_identifier + '.' + build.extentions)
file = open(path, 'rb')

response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/vnd.android.package-archive')
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(path)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment'.format(
    translit(build.name.replace(' ', '_'), 'ru', reversed=True),
    build.number,
    build.build_type)

return response
```

The problem is that when you open the link starts the download.

Is it possible to do anything to start the installation?